# How to get this  drop down menu to work in IE 8?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-float

The menu works fine in Firefox, chrome and older IEs but not in IE8.
Ive been sitting for hours but i cant get it to work.
Please help me out.
Here´s menu in question: [hugoth](http://www.hugoth.com)

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you mean by "does not work". It does not look good for me and I am using Chrome which you say does look good so I guess I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: Last time i checked in chrome it looked ok but now i see that its even more messed up than IE8. Thanks for letting me know!   Anyway, the menu is supposed to be aligned in the middle, in one row and without the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

The menu works, but the problem you're having is the menu is displaying within the table cell (note the scroll bar on the right side of that cell). A simple fix is to add `z-index:1;` to all the elements.... even the parent element of the menu (i.e. the `td`).

A more time consuming solution is to rewrite your code to use div's instead of tables. This is harder to do since you have to re-write your code, but in doing so it will display correctly across all browsers (with the exception of IE5.5).

Just my 2 cents

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! ive added to every css element but to no avail. I even changed to a simpler drop-down menu as it was easier to edit but still no change. Ive upped the edited page here : http://hugoth.com/test2/index.htm    Are you able to see whats wrong?

Comment: Try adding `left:-30px` to the li:hover ul css call. http://www.mbeuropeandelivery.com/ is a site I did it on a few months back. I had to give each sub element a static height width, but it works.